# How to make a Device(ethernet) to use a specific driver(user made network driver)

Tags: linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi3

I've written a network driver for ethernet , How to make the ethernet to use my driver code rather using the default driver in the kernel.

I'm trying to visualise the data transfer via OSI layers by adding prink at each layer of transmission (to be displayed in dmesg).

Comment: You may blacklist the original one.

Comment: If your arch uses the Device Tree, then the driver for the device is specified through the device node's `compatible` property.